# How to call a template for each occurrence of a unique list

Tags: xml, unique, grouping, xslt-2.0

I'm currently using XSLT 2.0 to try and process a high volume of data. My goal is to call a specific template for unique occurrence of a specific node throughout the data. I cannot use "apply template" as I have other templates that need to be used based on different logic.  The xml is structured something like this:

```
<root>
  <row>
     <date>date1</date>
     <child>
        <ID>001</ID>
     </child>
  </row>
  <row>
     <date>date2</date>
     <child>
        <ID>002</ID>
     </child>
  </row>
  <row>
     <date>date1</date>
     <child>
        <ID>002</ID>
     </child>
  </row>
  <row>
     <date>date3</date>
     <child>
        <ID>002</ID>
     </child>
  </row>
</root>
```

Ideally, what would happen is that I would call the template twice in this scenario since there are two unique IDs 001 and 002, regardless of how many dates appear on that ID. I have seen several instances where people have either used Keys or the preceding-sibling approach; however, I can never seem to get the syntax right.  I have tried the following approaches:

Template being called:

```
<xsl:template name='doSomething'/>
   <xsl:value-of select='child/ID'/>
   <xsl:value-of select='date'/>
</template>
```

====================

```
<xsl:for-each select='/root/row[not(child/ID = current()child/ID)]
   <xsl:call-template name='doSomething'/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

====================

```
<xsl:key name='IDs' match='root/row/child/ID' use='.'/>

<xsl:for-each select='root/row[generate-id() = generate-id(key("IDs",.)[1])]>
    <xsl:call-template name='doSomething'/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

====================

```
<xsl:for-each select='root/row/child/ID[not(. = preceding-sibling::row/child/ID)]>
   <xsl:call-template name='doSomething'/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I apologize if this is horrendous coding, as this is my very first time attempting anything this sophisticated with XSLT and I still have trouble understanding key use and how the axis syntax works. I typically use for-each-group in 2.0. However, when attempting the for-each-group here, I get all the entries instead of the unique entries, which makes me think I do not fully understand how grouping works. My original attempt was this:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select='root/row' group-by='child/ID'>
    <xsl:call-template name='doSomething'/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

====================

I also tried this:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select='root/row' group-by='child/ID[1]'>
   <xsl:call-template name='doSomething'/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

====================

I know this wasn't entirely correct, but I ran out of ideas and was just experimenting. Any direction or assistance in resolving this would be GREATLY appreciated. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Here is my desired output would be:

001date1
   002date2

However, I'm getting:

001date1
   002date2
   002date1
   002date3

EDIT: Thanks for the feedback, I realized I left out quite an important part of the code. There are dates associated with each ID as well, representing transaction dates. And while I can group by ID using for-each-group, I continue to get all the dates associated with that ID and I only want to call the template for the unique ID, not all entries that contain that ID - which is what is happening now. I added a sample output and current output.

I believe I may have misunderstood how apply-template works. I thought if I used apply-templates it would apply all templates in the xslt. Since I have 4 other templates that are used under specific conditions. The actual input xml has about 40 child nodes, are used for processing logic and information.

I hope that clarifies, please let me know if you need any further details.

**EDIT:**

After doing some more research, it seems like using a key would be a good method for me; however, I just cannot seem to get the syntax correct. Here is my attempt, could anyone help me correct it?

```
<xsl:key name='IDs' match='child' use='ID'/>

<xsl:template match='/'>
   <xsl:for-each select='root/row/child[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key("IDs", ID)[1])]>
       <xsl:call-template name='doSomething'/>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks in advance for any clarification.

Comment: Actually, templates *can* be applied in your case -- just use the `mode` attribute. So, you can use the good solution by @MartinHonnen by adding modes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay on this response.  Here is the solution I came up with. I don't know if it's the most elegant solution, but it worked very well for me. Perhaps some feedback on while this would be a poor solution would be appreciated.

```
    <xsl:for-each-group select='root/Row' group-by='concat(child/ID,date)'>
        <xsl:sort select='child/ID'/>
        <xsl:call-template name='DoSomething'/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
```

Thank you.

Comment: The original solution I came up with ended up not being robust enough and wasn't applying accurately every time. This was the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really explained what the problem is, by showing us the output you want, the code you have, the result you get.

I don't see any problems using `apply-templates` or if you insist on it using `call-template` together with the `for-each-group` you have posted.

Here is a sample showing both approaches:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <apply-templates>
     <xsl:for-each-group select="root/row" group-by="child/ID">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
     </xsl:for-each-group>
   </apply-templates>
   <call-template>
     <xsl:for-each-group select="root/row" group-by="child/ID">
       <xsl:call-template name="foo"/>
     </xsl:for-each-group>
   </call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root/row">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="foo">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the input

```
<root>
  <row>
     <child>
        <ID>value</ID>
     </child>
  </row>
  <row>
     <child>
        <ID>value2</ID>
     </child>
  </row>
  <row>
     <child>
        <ID>value2</ID>
     </child>
  </row>
</root>
```

with Saxon 9.4 I get the output

```
<apply-templates>
   <row>
     <child>
        <ID>value</ID>
     </child>
  </row>
   <row>
     <child>
        <ID>value2</ID>
     </child>
  </row>
</apply-templates>
<call-template>
   <row>
     <child>
        <ID>value</ID>
     </child>
  </row>
   <row>
     <child>
        <ID>value2</ID>
     </child>
  </row>
</call-template>
```

so both approaches process the `row` elements you are interested in, as far as I understand your description.

If you still have problems then please show minimal but complete samples of XSLT, output you get, the one you want, and details of the XSLT 2.0 processor you use, so that we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to everyone who provided feedback, after some further research over the weekend and a little experimenting I was able to get the solution!

Input:

```
<root>
  <row>
     <date>date1</date>
     <child>
         <id>001</id>
     </child>
  </row>
  <row>
     <date>date1</date>
     <child>
         <id>002</id>
     </child>
  </row>
  <row>
     <date>date2</date>
     <child>
         <id>002</id>
     </child>
  </row>
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:for-each select='root/row'>
    <xsl:if test='preceding-sibling::row[1]/child/id != child/id'>
         <xsl:call-template name='doSomething'/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Output:

001date1, 002date1